Magicdraw datahub CSV sunc
Im using Magicdraw 2021x with dataHub plugin, what is the best way to gain more practical experience with the Datahub plugin in order to import and sync with an external CSV file ?
I'd like also to manage the changes in the CSV file , so I'll have the ability to see the changes previously done
P.S : The requirement table managed and maintained through this CSV file
I didn't found any tutorial regarding this topic. I just wonder if there
is a guide that can help me with this issue, including managing changes between the model and the CSV file
